# Using Typescript Type System to check the existence of key in an inner object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a deeply nested inner object as such:

```
const TOKENS = {
    USDT: {
        address: "0xUSDT",
        WETH: "0xWETHUSDT", // LPool<TYPES.USDT, TYPES.WETH>
    },
    WETH: {
        address: "0xWETH",
        USDT: "0xUSDTWETH", // LPool<TYPES.WETH, TYPES.USDT>
    }
};
```

And the following namespaces defined:

```
namespace TYPES {
    export type USDT = "USDT";
    export type WETH = "WETH";
}

namespace CONSTS {
    export const USDT = "USDT" as const;
    export const WETH = "WETH" as const;
}
```

I also have a function call `swap` defined as such:

```
function swap<Token0 extends Token, Token1 extends Token>(contact: LPool<Token0, Token1>):  {
    return;
}
```

I want to make sure that if `swap` is called with the wrong generic type parameters, an error is raised at compile time like so:

```
swap<TYPES.USDT, TYPES.USDT>("USDT") // Should raise Error
```

This is because `TOKENS.USDT.USDT` is not a property on the object:

```
TOKENS.USDT = {
        address: "0xUSDT",
        WETH: "0xWETHUSDT", // LPool<TYPES.USDT, TYPES.WETH>
}
```

`Token` is defined like so:

```
type Token = keyof typeof TOKENS; // type Token = "USDT" | "WETH"
```

I have been working on this for 4 hours to no avail. I do not have a working definition of `LPool`, what I have is:

```
type LPool<Token0 extends Token, Token1 extends Token> = /* not sure what to write here */
```

Comment: `const USDT = "USDT" as const;` The `as const` is redundant.

Comment: Missing some definitions; `Token`, `LPool`

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to clearly see your issue without encountering unrelated issues like missing declarations.

Comment: @jcalz  I have edited my question to avoid the missing declarations problem.

Comment: I don't know what `LPool` is supposed to be either, since you haven't shown a valid use of it, just an invalid one.  I can figure out that your type parameters should be indexing into `typeof TOKENS`, as shown [here in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NBBBxN), but as for what you want to be accepted/rejected in `LPool` I won't know until and unless you [edit] to show your use cases.  Let me know how you'd like to proceed.